# Why is `heightForRowAt` implemented in `UITableViewDelegate` and not `UITableViewDataSource`?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This question is a bit more pedagogical in nature, but why is `heightForRowAt` implemented in `UITableViewDelegate` and not `UITableViewDataSource`?

Doesn't it make more sense for row height to be defined in `UITableViewDataSource`?

Since the height of a row should depend on the contents of that particular row, and therefore by extension the data source?

Comment: `UITableviewDatasource` is focused on DATA (ie: number of row, provide cell class and how populate with the data, titles for header/footers, etc., not View/UserInterfaction. That's why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Tableview is a pretty complex view and aas a view it must be reusable. This can only be achieved if some of the aspects of a table view are left to  other classes. The table view uses two classes a delegate and a datasource.

The datasource is responsible for the data that needs to be shown in the table. This dat comes from a model object in the MVC paradigm.

The delegate is responsible for how the table should represent itself. Although the height of a row is a piece of data and might give you the idea that it should be a method of the datasource, the height of a row sets a layout item of the table view and therefore the representation of the table view.

For this reason heightForRowAt is a delegate method and not a datasource method.

Kind regards,
MacUserT

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I appreciate it.